# android - Material button color

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-styles

I am styling my app and want to set the button background color and keep them material-like.

## I want

Set button background color

## I do

### 1.

I am create style for button, set the `colorPrimary` and set button style and `colorButtonNormal`. And it works.

```
style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

...

<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

### 2.

But I want to do one button with different color. I tried to use `backgroundTint`, but It doesn't work. So I create style:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Button.Wildberries" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/wildberries</item>
</style>
```

It works on Android 4.x, but on Android 5.x button is still `colorAccent`.

### 3.

I create style-v21 for button:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Button.Wildberries" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/wildberries</item>
</style>
```

**Works in Android Studio:**

[image: IDE]

Works on Android 4.x too

**But doesn't work on 5.x**

[image]

### 4.

Also I tried to use `AppCompat.Button`:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/wildberries"
            
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Перейти на сайт"
            android:id="@+id/WildBtn"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button.Wildberries"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null" />
```

And got nothing:

[image]

On Android 4.x device button is still purple, on 5.x still green.

**So, what is the way to set button background color on android 4.x and hihger?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just using AppCompatButton by setting the attribute `"app:backgroundTint="@color/wildberries"` and make sure your activity extends AppCompatActivity. 
I just use it in my project. It works like a charm in both 5.X and pre-5.X.

Comment: Just a warnning: `app:backgroundTint="@color/wildberries"` isn't implemented in all the `View`s.

Comment: it will override colors for all states, disabled button will be the same as enabled button